# Word 2010 - Force Formatting In Specific Parts of Document

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

I am working with Microsoft Word 2010. I have a document that serves as a template for multiple users for a project I am working on. There are two parts of the document I want to force formatting when a user types:

1. Enter in an email address - I want the address to not automatically turn to a hyperlink. I want it to not turn to a hyperlink on just this part of the document. The rest of it I want hyperlinks to be enabled.
2. Enter in a URL without www in front (i.e. google.com), and not have the first letter automatically capitalize. I don't want to turn off capitalizing the first letter of a sentence in the whole document. Just in this part of the document.

Is this something that can be done? I tried messing with Fields but did not have any luck. I am familiar with VBA so if there is a way to do this with code, I am open to that too.

Answer (score 1):

Both features you requires are implemented in Word using AutoCorrect/AutoFormat. They are not controlled by the style mechanism and consequently can't be selectively activated.

The mail address formatting can be controlled by styles, and you could prevent the switch to the Hyperlink style from being visible. You could also consider a macro that selectively changes the styles of the text as required in a post-processing pass through the documents - perhaps the next time the document is opened by a user for review.